# How to automatically convert json null values to empty string in Codeigniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am working with json in Codeigniter and i have some fields which outputs null values i want to change those null values to empty string. I don't want to check every fields one by one.My CI code is like this:

```
$result= $this->get_model->get_model();
header("content-type: application/json");
$data[] = array('name'=>"result",'data'=>$result);
echo json_encode(array('success'=> 1,'posts'=>$data));
return $result;
```

[image]

Comment: once you convert into the the string. Replacae `null` with empty string

Comment: Can u please explain it with example or give me a link for that

Comment: can you let me know what output `echo json_encode(array('success'=> 1,'posts'=>$data));` this line prints.

Comment: this is the code snippet : "name":"latest",
"data":[
{
"timestamp":"2015-11-16 11:34:03",
"avg_rating":null
}
]

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It prints json replacing null values with empty

```
$result= $this->get_model->get_model();
header("content-type: application/json");
$data[] = array('name'=>"result",'data'=>$result);
$data_result = json_encode(array('success'=> 1,'posts'=>$data));

echo str_replace("null","",$data_result);

return $result;
```

Comment: I tried the above code but the same null values are coming.

Comment: what my code `echo` prints, please let me know  and what is the value of `$data_result`

Comment: print_r($data_result); it outputs nothing this means there is no value in $data_result.

Comment: `$data_result` is a string. It is not an array. So, you should use `echo`

Comment: @sandeepsue- I am getting error in json i have uploaded the image where i am getting it.All avg_rating are changing like the above image.

Comment: Yes, Because it is replaced `null` with empty string. According to me you should replace `null` with 0.

Comment: if i replace it with 0 it is not inside single quotes eg. 0, i want it in quotes such as "0". And if possible how can i replace it with empty string because in my case i am getting error in json parse if i use empty string such as "".

Comment: In my above code try to replace line of code with `echo str_replace("null"," ",$data_result);` and check.

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest way:

```
array_walk_recursive($array,function(&$item){$item=strval($item);});
```

From: https://developertipsandtricks.blogspot.com/2013/10/convert-null-to-empty-string-for-json.html